# Function not working when parameters entered

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to use JavaScript to swap out a picture on mouseover. I’ve already got working code for a single picture, but as I have to do this with multiple pictures, I want to use parameters. Whenever I enter a parameter though, nothing seems to be happening. I’ve tested to make sure that the function is actually called in my HTML (it is) but other than that, I don’t know what to do.

Here's what I have (the second one doesn’t work):

```
function change() {
document.getElementById(“LJindivid”).src = “AOindivid.jpg”;
}

function change1(old, new) {
document.getElementById(“old”).src = “new”;
}
```

Comment: 1. You seem to be using curly quotes, none of that will work. 2. In the second example you're using strings, not the values of the parameters.

Comment: new is a keyword in js, chose anothe param name

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things...

1. `new` is a keyword in javascript and should be change to something like `newSrc`
2. You don't need to wrap the parameters in quotes. `document.getElementById(old)`

The final code should look something like...

```js
function change1(oldID, newSrc) {
    document.getElementById(oldID).src = newSrc;
}
```

See the working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/o6rn2d90/

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. Just clarifying: is the reason I don’t need to wrap the parameters in quotes because they hold values rather than strings of text?

Comment: @LaurenJ Essentially, yes.